# The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have hosted ASP.NET MVC website on **Windows Server**, but when use login page to log in the user this error appear (The error happens on the server):

```
The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the <machineKey> configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

There are one AntiForgeryToken() in the view, I review all code many times but not catch error

This the code of Log in Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ShowErrorMessages("InValid Password");
                return View(model);
            }
            var email = Business.User.Instance.GetUserEmail();

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, model.Password.Trim(), model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ShowErrorMessages("Not Valid Password");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

This the code of view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="col-12">
                    <br />
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 30 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <br />
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>

            }
```

This the web.config:

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=134.154.22.53;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <system.web>  
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="533000" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.cshtml"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

I try many attempts but cannot catch it

Comment: Does this happen in Visual Studio? On the server? While debugging? What kind of hosting? Need a lot more info about the environment.

Comment: On the server, I have ssl https

Comment: It is windows host

Comment: you sure the target framework should be 4.7.2?  If using core, it'll be 3.x, or .net5, 6, or 7.  4 was skipped to prevent confusion with old .net framework.

Comment: wait, I think I see the problem here... you may have inserted 2 anti-forgery hidden fields.  I believe Html.BeginForm() will automatically include a anti-forgery token/hidden field.  Then you are inserting another with @Html.AntiForgeryToken()... (which effectively uses two different encryption keys??)

Comment: I am not using core, and when I remove the AntiForgeryToken()    this error appear:   The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Comment: This mean there no hidden AntiForgeryToken()

Comment: Your project is Asp.Net Framework or asp.net core? If your project is Asp.Net Framework, Please remote the `asp.net core ` Tag.

Comment: the cookie is separate...  I would check the browser to see what cookies are set.  It sounds like something's preventing the writing of the cookie.

Comment: @pcalkins  I checked the browser, I cannot catch the reason, can you help me Mr.pcalkins please  - If you some few time please contact me with this email:   mos.prog@gmail.com Thnaks